# File is not uploading to server in ionic 3 from browser

Tags: php, ionic-framework, browser, ionic3

I am developing in ionic 3, I want to upload file from browser and upload it to server.

My code is as below

Html code

```
 <input type="file" name="file"  (change)="upload($event)" />
```

ts code

```
upload(str:any)
      {
        const formData = new FormData();

        this.image=str.target.files[0];

        formData.append('files[]', this.image);
        console.log(formData,this.image);

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
        const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


     this.http.post("https://myserver/demofile.php",formData,requestOptions)
       .subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
    console.log(str);

      }
```

Php code is as below

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $errors = [];
        $path = 'attachment/';
      $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];

        $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);  
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][0];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][0];
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][0])));
            $file_name = uniqid().".".$file_ext;
            $file = $path . $file_name;
            if (empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
            }

        if ($errors) print_r($errors);    }
}
?>
```

I am getting error as

> ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false,
>   statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}

Please help me

Comment: Internal server error means your PHP server is giving an error, Check your Php Application Server Log to see what the problem is

Comment: @BundayyOlayinka I have updated error